# Is the GNU C Library usable on non-GNU (or POSIX) platforms?

Tags: c, windows, gnu, glibc

Just wondering, is the GNU C Library (glibc) usable on non-GNU and/or non-POSIX platforms such as Microsoft Windows?

Comment: Can a fish walk outside of the sea?

Comment: I think the better question is, is it available. How are you going to use it in Windows when it simply isn't there?

Comment: If you are using Cygwin, sure.

Comment: preferably without cygwin, but yes, is it available? I guess no...? Just want to know so my programs will be portable

Comment: I don't think cygwin helps much. You can't really layer implementations of the C library on top of one another, and the whole way Cygwin works is by being a POSIX-emulating C library layer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, its possible in theory, but not really worth it in practice. You would need to port the syscall interface, dynamic linker, and other parts to Windows or your platform of choice, and Glibc is not an ideal candidate for this.

If you really need a self contained C library, I would consider [newlib](http://sourceware.org/newlib/) or [uClibc](http://www.uclibc.org/) (or FreeBSD's/OpenBSD's libc) over glibc. Glibc is a complex beast, the alternatives are much smaller and easier to understand.

Comment: +1 for calling glibc a "beast" and recommending alternatives. Bonus points if you find the right compiler options to make the glibc build tree weigh in at 666 MB.

Answer (score 2):

It is provided that glibc has been ported to the kernel in question. It may however be easier to use [Gnulib](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/) instead as a wrapper around the native API.