# glibc not supported by Cygwin

Tags: linux, cygwin, porting, glibc, newlib

Cygwin FAQ has the following info for 'Where is glibc?' :
Cygwin does not provide glibc. It uses newlib instead, which provides much (but not all) of the same functionality. Porting glibc to Cygwin would be difficult.

I was surprised and checked out the release packages as i had earlier used it. While i checked the repositories, it appears that glibc was actually indeed part of cygwin until version 2.10.  Can anyone tell of the porting difficulty for the subsequent versions of glibc ?

Comment: The Cygwin FAQ entry quoted is at https://www.cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.programming.glibc

Answer (score 3):

The Cygwin FAQ is correct, of course; glibc has **never** been part of Cygwin.  The C library on Cygwin is `cygwin1.dll` (part of the `cygwin` package), which is based on newlib.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207585/is-the-gnu-c-library-usable-on-non-gnu-or-posix-platforms). Port glibc to OS like Windows is horrible work. Maybe the worst part is port all system call interface to SO non-POSIX. Glibc is a monster. There are other options if you need a C Lib: [newlib](https://sourceware.org/newlib/) and [uClibc](http://www.uclibc.org/)