# regex issue Bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I'm studying bash programming , in particular the regex and I found this code:

```
numpat='^[+-]([0-9]+)$'
strpat='^([a-z]*)\1$'

read stringa

if [[ $stringa =~ $numpat ]]
then
    echo "numero"
    echo numero > output
    exit ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
elif [[ $stringa =~ $strpat ]]
then
    echo "echo"
    echo echo > output
    exit 11
fi
```

and I don't understand what means `\1` in this line:

```
strpat='^([a-z]*)\1$'
```

Comment: Have you read any regular expression tutorials? They should explain what each of the elements of the expression means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\1` is a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html). It matches whatever was matched by the first capture group `([a-z]*)`.

So the pattern `^([a-z]*)\1$` matches a string that built from a substring that's repeated twice, such as `foofoo`. The capture group matches the first `foo`, and the backreference matches the second `foo`. But if the string is `foobar`, the backreference never matches anything, because it can't find another repetition of any of the initial strings.

You can allow any number of repetitions by using the `+` quantifier after `\1`. This matches it one or more times.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tL8oP4/1)

Comment: I also think so. However, having `*` as a pattern makes it greedy so it will probably not match anything else. If I test it, it doesn't work: `[[ "foofoo" =~ ^([a-z]*)\1$ ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"` returns `no`.

Comment: ok thanks for this explanation , but if I want to match the group ([a-z]*) N times , How do I use backreference?

Comment: `^([a-z]*)\1\1\1\1$` will match 5 repetitions.

Comment: If you want to allow any number of repetitions, you can use `^([a-z]*)\1+$`.

Comment: While I can reproduce this behaviour, per definition *extended posix regexes* does **not** support back references.

Comment: Strangely `[[ 'foofoo' =~ ^([a-z]*)\1$ ]] && echo matched || echo no` prints `no` for me on `bash 4.3.33(1)-release`

Comment: @hek2mgl oh, interesting. Could you provide a source for this?

Comment: I checked the man page of grep, and found a section `Back References and Subexpressions`. Looks like at least GNU grep/egrep does not behave according to standards.

Comment: @hek2mgl GNU utilities often extend the standard behavior.

Comment: Yep!.. @anubhava Do you have GNU/Linux?

Comment: I tried same on Ubuntu BASH `4.3.11(1)-release` and it still printed `no` and [so it does here on this demo](http://ideone.com/P8dqLh)

Comment: I was just explaining the generic meaning of backreferences. I assumed that bash actually implements them because the OP got the code from a bash tutorial.

Comment: The difference seems to be whether the pattern is in a variable or a literal.

Comment: yes ok a general number of matching I can do this : ^([a-z]*)\1+$     but if I want to matching exactly 5 times for example?

Comment: @ginogino I showed that earlier: `\1\1\1\1` matches exactly 4 repetitions.

Comment: @ginogino You can also do `^([a-z]*)\1{4}$`

Comment: @Barmar: "The difference seems to be whether the pattern is in a variable or a literal" - not on my machine. it just matches `1`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath What version of bash?

Answer (score 2):

On **cygwin**, which uses *newlib*, `\1` matches only `1`.

```
if [[ a1 =~ $strpat ]]; then echo YES; fi   # YES
```

Comment: Not in *my* bash. In *my* bash it works like a back reference, meaning it matches `foofoo` but not `foobar`. That's weird! I have `GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release`.

Comment: seriously? bash 4.1.10(4)-release here on cygwin.

Comment: @hek2mgl Bash uses ERE as in `man 3 regex`, and back reference is not in the ERE standard, although it may be supported in some implementations.

Comment: in my bash it works , my problem isn't if works or not , but what does \1 mean

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yes, seriously. Couldn't believe that! Let me check on a different machine, different bash.

Comment: I've also tried `GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` from Ubuntu 15.10. The first bash was from Gentoo. Both show the same results: \1 works as a back reference. I mean, I'm with you; The extended POSIX regex standard does not define back references! However this page says that some implementations support them: http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html

Comment: Haha! Check `man grep`! And search for *Back References and Subexpressions*. Looks like the GNU folks extended the standard... :)

Comment: unfortunately there are many regex variants.... no surprise there, the `grep` back references work just fine on my machine.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I've tested a bash-4.1 on Linux, it supports back references.. Can you check `ldd /bin/bash` and tell which version of libc you are using? AFAIK the libc handles the regex compilation.

Comment: @hek2mgl: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952829/glibc-not-supported-by-cygwin